# Homebrew No Such Keg

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

When I was trying to fix a problem with

```
brew uninstall gcc
```

I got the error

```
No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc
```

But actually I have gcc installed as

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

It seems like brew is pointing somewhere empty. i.e.I also have python installed under `/usr/bin/` but `brew info python` showed `Not installed`.

How can I fix this to link all these tools to brew? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brew info python` and `brew uninstall gcc` look in your Cellar for installed packages. You don't have these installed in your Cellar, but have them installed on your system.

The Cellar is found at `/usr/local/Cellar/`. Each directory there is a separate keg.

You can do `ls -al /usr/bin/gcc` to see where it is getting the binary from - from what you've posted here it isn't from `brew`.

To see which packages are installed in your Cellar (and to confirm that they're not there), do `brew list`.

To understand more about `brew` and its terminology, see [the Homebrew Formula Cookbook](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook)